# Replacing a value in a config file

Tags: ruby, git

I have a file that looks like:

```
my.githash="asdfsadfdsf"
some.key=234
some.blue=abchello
russia.green="asdfdsf"
```

I want to replace the string for the key my.githash with an up to date git hash vlaue.

How can I use ruby to update my configuration file?

To get the git hash value I will be using:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

Comment: Use a real config file format, one that provides the ability to read, modify and store configuration data. Consider YAML or INI formats.

Comment: @meagar the config file is something that I can't really change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gsub` you can replace a string using a regular expression match. In your case it's a little bit tricky because you don't know exactly the match.

Hence you can use

```
string.gsub(/(githash="(.+)")/) { $1.gsub($2, 'NEW_SHA') }
```

You can fetch the `NEW_SHA` running a shell command.

```
sha = `git rev-parse HEAD`
string.gsub(/(githash="(.+)")/) { $1.gsub($2, sha) }
```

and read the file from the file system

```
sha = `git rev-parse HEAD`
content = File.read('/path/to/fike')
content.gsub!(/(githash="(.+)")/) { $1.gsub($2, sha) }
File.write('/path/to/fike', content)
```

This is a very simple example. You can optimize it further. You can also use a single `gsub`, but it will require you to write twice the delimiters.

```
content.gsub!(/githash="(.+)"/, %Q{githash="#{sha}"})
```

Another (longer but perhaps more accurate) way is to write a simple parser that loads the file in a Hash parsing each line (as lines seems to follow a specific syntax), and then dumps the Hash back in a formatted file.

Comment: You can squeeze al the code in one line replacing the variable assignments.